# Set object properties if truthy in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to transfer properties from `objA` to `objB` while changing their *names* and overriding only if they are *truthy*. Using lodash but an ES6 solution would be even better.

This is what I have so far:

```
// My initial objects
const objA = {a: 1, b: '', c: null};
const objB = {x: 7, y: 8, z: 9};

// Extracting and renaming
let {x: a, y: b, z: c} = obj1;

// Sanitizing
const temp = _.pickBy({x, y, z}, _.identity);

// Merging A and B
return {...objB, ...objA}; // {x: 1, y: 8, z: 9}
```

Is there a less contrived way of doing this?

Comment: Seems like using a Map would be a lot saner.

Comment: FWIW, `{...objB, ...objA}` is not valid ES6. Object spread is a proposal. If you are willing to accept answers that use experimental features you should tag your question with [tag:ecmascript-next].

Comment: has `objB` always the keys `{x, y, z}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solution use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to rename array keys, and [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge objects (the snippets don't support object rest/spread).

**ES2017**

Use [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (ES2017) to get the keys and values of `objA`, rename and add them only if the value is not falsy.

```js
const a2x = new Map([['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['c', 'z']]);

const objA = {a: 1, b: '', c: null};
const objB = {x: 7, y: 8, z: 9};

const result = Object.assign({}, objB, 
  Object.entries(objA).reduce((r, [k, v]) => v ? 
    Object.assign(r, { [a2x.get(k)]: v }) : r, {}));

console.log(result);
```

**lodash:**

Use [`_.mapKeys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys) to change the names of the keys, then [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy) with [`_.identity()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#identity) to remove falsy values.

```js
const a2x = new Map([['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['c', 'z']]);

const objA = {a: 1, b: '', c: null};
const objB = {x: 7, y: 8, z: 9};

const result = Object.assign({}, objB, 
  _.pickBy(_.mapKeys(objA, (v, k) => a2x.get(k)), _.identity));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```